# How do I know if GCC produced warning inside a shell script?

Tags: bash, scripts, gcc

I am writing a gcc wrapper that will invoke gcc on my source file with the `-Wall` compile flag set. If there is no errors or warnings, it will execute the output binary.

The exit status off gcc will be 1 if there is a error. But it will be zero even if there is a warning.

So how do I detect if gcc produced any warnings in my shell script?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add to the gcc command the option `-Werror` which 
makes all warnings into errors.